# SFTP to local ubuntu server crashes network

Tags: networking, 14.04, server, mac, sftp

I have an Ubuntu server (named vader) running in my house that I would like to set up SFTP connections with my Mac (named MacbookBro).

From vader, when I run:

> sftp mourkeer@MacbookBro.local

It connects just fine. However, from MacbookBro (or any other machine), if I run:

> sftp mourkeer@vader.local

My entire LAN crashes, and I have to reboot the router.

So my Ubuntu machine can send SFTP requests, but it can't receive them. FTP, SCP, and most importantly, SSH all work to/from either machine. What could be causing my network to crash? I'm assuming it's some sort of time out, and my router just sucks. But that doesn't explain why the issue is happening to begin with.

Vader is connected by ethernet to my Linksys E2500 router. MacbookBro is connected wirelessly.
I was running Ubuntu 13.10 before, but I fruitlessly upgraded to 14.04 hoping that might fix the problem.

Comment: A big problem with solving this is your statement -"My entire LAN crashes, and I have to reboot the router.". This is pretty much impossible. For instance -Does the wireless signal on your Macbook disappear? What about the LEDs on the back of your router?

Comment: I guess I misspoke. My LAN is still technically up, but what I mean when I say the LAN crashes is that all devices lose internet connection. I don't know how else to explain it. Google is unreachable for all devices until the router is rebooted.

Comment: Can you `ping` local machines? Who is delivering DNS-services on your network?

Answer (score 0):

I posted an [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/510916/294653) on your previous post. I'm not sure if this line can be considered an *answer* to this question, but simply duplicating it seems odd.

Comment: I made a separate thread because the original was both not getting much attention (I posted it late at night) and the problem was narrowed down to a point where the original question was misleading (I.e., FTP actually works just fine). Apparently this wasn't the best approach. I'll look into your answer this weekend.